# Get inserted document counts in specific date range using date histogram in elasticsearch

Tags: date, elasticsearch, search, date-histogram

I have list documents in elasticsearch which contains various fileds.
documents looks like below.

```
    {
        "role": "api_user",
        "apikey": "key1"
        "data":{},
        "@timestamp": "2021-10-06T16:47:13.555Z"
    },
    {
        "role": "api_user",
        "apikey": "key1"
        "data":{},
        "@timestamp": "2021-10-06T18:00:00.555Z"
    },
    {
        "role": "api_user",
        "apikey": "key1"
        "data":{},
        "@timestamp": "2021-10-07T13:47:13.555Z"
    }
]
```

I wanted to find the number of documents present in specifi date range with 1day interval, let's say
`2021-10-05T00:47:13.555Z to 2021-10-08T00:13:13.555Z`

I am trying the below aggregation for the result.

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "range": {
                            "@timestamp": {
                                "gte": "2021-10-05T00:47:13.555Z",
                                "lte": "2021-10-08T00:13:13.555Z",
                                "format": "strict_date_optional_time"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "data": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "@timestamp",
                "calendar_interval": "day"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The expected output  should be:-
For `2021-10-06` I should get 2 documents and `2021-10-07` I should get 1 document and if the docs are not present I should get count as 0.

Answer (score 0):

the below solution works

```json
{
   "size":0,
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            
         ],
         "filter":[
            {
               "match_all":{
                  
               }
            },
            {
               "range":{
                  "@timestamp":{
                     "gte":"2021-10-05T00:47:13.555Z",
                     "lte":"2021-10-08T00:13:13.555Z",
                     "format":"strict_date_optional_time"
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "should":[
            
         ],
         "must_not":[
            
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs":{
      "data":{
         "date_histogram":{
            "field":"@timestamp",
            "fixed_interval":"12h",
            "time_zone":"Asia/Calcutta",
            "min_doc_count":1
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).